# Making DOM Reflow/Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js, reflow

I'm new to JavaScript and D3, and I'm trying to modify some attributes of a DOM element and then have the page reflow/refresh so I can see those updated changes. The trick is that I need this to happen automatically without any kind of onclickevent or button click or mouse movement or anything.

I've tried everything I could find on the internet and nothing has worked, but oddly enough, if I call an alert() right before the line that changes my element's attributes, when I click okay, the element repositions itself on the screen. I need this to happen without having to call an alert() and click okay.

Here's the code in question:

```
alert("HI")
$("#g1").attr("transform", "translate(0,10)");
```

If I delete the alert line, my element never moves. If I leave it there, and click okay, then as soon as I do, my element repositions itself.

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#g1").attr("transform", "translate(0,10)");
});
```

in order to ensure that the DOM is loaded before you try to execute the code.

Your alert is getting the page time to load before continuing with the code, which is why that line seems to "fix" the problem.

Comment: And if `document.ready` doesn't do the trick, try `$(window).on("load",function(){...});`